# Filter by custom field 'meta_key', 'meta_value' for archive

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I'm using a custom field `'meta_key' => 'author_name'` for guest posts (no user profiles), and I manually enter the value of the author name for each post.

Is it possible to filter the `'meta_key'` and `'meta_value'` as a link to:

`example.com/author_name/guest001/`
or
`example.com/?author_name=guest001`

and display the posts, so that works very similarly to category, tag, or real author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to add the rewrite tag like this:

```
function createRewriteRules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    // add rewrite tokens
    $authorname = '%authorname%';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag($authorname, '(.+?)', 'author-name=');

    $keywords_structure = $wp_rewrite->root . "author-name/$authorname/";
    $keywords_rewrite = $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules($keywords_structure);

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $keywords_rewrite + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'createRewriteRules');
```

then hook generate rules and add your rewrite rule:

```
function add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) 
{
        add_rewrite_rule('^author-name/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=12&author-name=$matches[1]','top');
        //page_id is added hardcoded but you can get the page id using your own code/function
}
add_action('init', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

add the variable to query vars:

```
function query_vars($public_query_vars) {
    $public_query_vars[] = "author-name";
    return $public_query_vars;
add_filter('query_vars', 'query_vars');
```

and it should work, please use the [Developer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/developer/screenshots/) plugin to inspect your rewrite rules.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but where is this answer does `author-name` get associated with a post_meta query?

Comment: @Slam: old post indeed. Op handled that on his on way - probably a form where he asks for an username but doesn't create an account for the user but saves it as meta value.

Comment: Glad you are still around jnhghy. I'm asking because I need to do something very similar but with ID numbers in post-meta under the key `legacy_id`. What I am lacking is where in your code `author-name` becomes a postmeta query. `&author-name=$matches[1]` makes sense, and I see you set it as a query_vars, but how does the query know to search postmeta rather than just post?

Comment: @Slam 1st: you need to tag for me to be notified of your comment :). 2) the author-name is registered as correct query var in the first piece of code in the createRewriteRules function sorry I got back so late but as I said, I didn't got the notification. If you want I think you can create a new post with your question and link it here in the comments and I'll answer it. Best!

Comment: I have [a very similar question here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/302728/query-postmeta-based-on-meta-value-return-array-of-post-id/302828?noredirect=1#comment449768_302828), only I didn't specify I was looking for a archive based on a postmeta LIKE query.